# My Windows Service cannot instantiate

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am maintaining a Windows Service, which has a quite unfortunate bug. I can no longer debug the code because the service simply refuses to start. This is the error:

> Windows could not start the MyService service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion.

I inserted some log-to-file lines in the main method and it never comes past the instantiation of my windows service. It stops right before the line

```
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

So the Run method is never executed. I am guessing that it is the instantiation of MyService that fails. But how is that possible?

```
static void Main()
{
        //this line is reached

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new MyService() //halts here
        };

        //this line is never executed
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in the MyService constructor?

Comment: what does the constructor look like for `MyService`?

Comment: Have you got any more information in the event viewer? Also ensure that the account that you are running the service under is sufficiently permissioned.

Comment: Yes, I got info in the event viewer. It was basically an unhandled exception due to the fact that I had an incorrect configuration file. The windows service is supposed to parse an XML file on instantiation, but there was a ">" sign missing, which means it wasn't even a valid XML file. So the lesson must be to have good error handling in the constructor of a windows service. Thank you all for your help

Comment: Please include this as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**reposted reply from above:**

Yes, I got info in the event viewer. It was basically an unhandled exception due to the fact that I had an incorrect configuration file. The windows service is supposed to parse an XML file on instantiation, but there was a ">" sign missing, which means it wasn't even a valid XML file. So the lesson must be to have good error handling in the constructor of a windows service. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error just the other day. I don't know if it'll solve it for you, but here's how I fixed it:

After you install it, right click and go to Properties. Go to the Log On tab and make sure "Allow service to interact with desktop" is enabled.
I'm not sure why Windows 7 seems to require this.